# Sticky Footer Not Working Properly

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I've followed Ryan Fait's sticky footer [example](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) and for some reason my footer, while sticky, is clipping through the rest of the divs when you reduce the height of the browser. Anyone know why this is, I'm obviously missing something, I haven't ran into this problem before.

Link: http://lithbeauty.com/test/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your floats. Just add `clear:both` to your `.push` class. Also, you should remove the top margin and padding on your wrapper because it's forcing the height beyond 100% and creating an unnecessary scroll.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! Don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

```
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    min-height:100%;
}
#footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the CSS sticky-footer approach is deceptively simple, a nightmare really. @Yusef's solution above is much more straightforward. I made a variation on this that also implements this Javascript code:

```
function setFooter()
{
    var footer = document.getElementById("footer");

    var innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var offsetWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;

    var scroll = innerWidth - offsetWidth;

    if(scroll != 0)
    {
        footer.style.position = "relative";
    }
    else
    {
        footer.style.bottom = 25 + "px";
    }
}
```

As long as Yusef's CSS for the footer also contains `clear: both;`, when there is **no** scrollbar in the window the footer div will automatically align below the main-content div (and also set `onload = "setFooter();"` in the html body tag).
If there **is** a scrollbar in the window, the difference calculated by the scroll variable will be the integer amount that overflows (see my question for more info:  [Why are scrollTop, pageYOffset, and height all not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115166/why-are-scrolltop-pageyoffset-and-height-all-not-working)).
Watch these videos for implementing wrapper, main-content, and footer divs:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnhoQ-aLfvE&src_vid=UpZbLIfHSMw&annotation_id=annotation_777473&feature=iv