# Why are scrollTop, pageYOffset, and height all not working?

Tags: javascript, height, scrollbar, offset, scrolltop

I am trying to detect if there is a vertical scrollbar or not on the browser window (if the content exceeds the window height and overflows). I have tried `document.body.scrollTop`, `window.pageYOffset`, and `document.body.style.height`...  **none** of these are working!
Upon doing a `window.alert` test on variables initialized with these properties, `pageYOffset` always returns **0** no matter if there is a scrollbar or not, and the other two return what seems to be an empty String.
My only idea is that maybe CSS positioning conflicts are causing this, but there seem to be no such conflicts...  Any ideas, solutions, workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth
```

returns the width of the vertical scroll-bar of the browser-window, and `0` if there is no scroll-bar.

So, you could have a function...

```
function windowHasVerticalScrollbar () {
    return window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth > 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, IE8 and IE7 don't support the `window.innerWidth` value, so this technique will not work in those browsers. (However, it does work in IE9 and all the other browsers).

Also, since the `documentElement` is the `<html>` element (the root element of the web-page), if you set styles on that element (like margins, absolute positioning, etc.), the calculation may return incorrect results.

Comment: That is awesome! Thank you so much for your efforts. This seems to be a serious problem, where many people suggest to use any of the above mentioned approaches that weren't working... but this approach works perfectly. My only question now is what exactly does `innerWidth` and `offsetWidth` each respectively represent?

Comment: @Ian Read on MDN: [`clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientWidth), [`innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.innerWidth). Note: I use `clientWidth` now (instead of `offsetWidth`) - it now works in IE9 too

Comment: K, will do. Thanks for all your help @Sime.